# Ignoring Time-stamp in maven snapshot

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My jar in the maven repository snapshot consists of a time-stamp.

E.g.: `bigdata-1.1-20160401.022812.jar`. During the Jenkins build my script is looking for `bigdata-1.1.jar` but because it has a timestamp, the build is throwing an error saying `bigdata-1.1.jar` not found.

What can I do to ignore the timestamp while looking for the snapshot jar?

Comment: If your build is looking for `bigdata-1.1.jar` it means it is searching for a release version and not for snapshot version. What you have mentioned  `bigdata-1.1-20160401.022812.jar` is a SNAPSHOT version which means if you like use it you need to define it like this: `bigdata-1.1-SNASPHOT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore the timestamp. You can however select the latest version of the jar by replacing your version tag in pom file to :

```
<version>latest</version>
```

Comment: Will not work for releases and not for SNAPSHOT's. BTW: You should alway define the version explicit.